# Parse.com link fb to ParseUser

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

Say the following happens:

1. User logs into my app with fb, creates some objects
2. User logs out
3. User logs in with email/password, creates some objects
4. User auth's with fb and ParseUser.getCurrentUser() is linked to fb account
5. User logs out
6. User logs in with fb.

Which parseobjects will now be loaded for ParseUser.getCurrentUser()? the original objects that were linked to the fb account? or the objects that were linked to the email/pass login account? or both?

Answer (score 0):

Parse.com has special object (class) called "User"

This class has special field - "authData" where you can link your Facebook or Twitter account. (Please, see snapshot attached).

There are different mechanism for login your current Parse user:

1) via username and password

[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:@"User Name"
                                             password:@"Password"

2) via Facebook

[PFFacebookUtils logInWithPermissions:permissionsArray block:

for link PFUser with FB:

[PFFacebookUtils linkUser:[PFUser currentUser] permissions:permissionsArray block:

So, return to your question, this scenario should be avoided on "Sign Up/Sign In" phase. During registration you can ask "email/phone number" and use this data as starting point.

OR

Sign Up via Facebook than ask email (or move this possibility to User Profile Settings).

In other case, you will have 2 users (PFUser class) without possibility to merge them.

[image: User Class Example]